# How to select from data frame using column order stored in another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames with equal number of rows. The snippet is

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c('3', '2', '1'), X2 = c('1,2', '1,3', '1'))
df1
  X1  X2
1  3 1,2
2  2 1,3
3  1   1
df2 <- data.frame(X1_1 = c(3, 2, 1), X1_2 = c(1, 1, 2), X1_3 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_1 = c(1, 1, 1), X2_2 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_3 = c(3, 2, 2))
df2
  X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3
1    3    1    2    1    2    3
2    2    1    3    1    3    2
3    1    2    3    1    3    2
```

`df1` stores column numbers of `df2` from which I need to take elements. `df1$X1` is `df2$X1_`-th column in the subset `X1_...` of `df2`. `df1$X2` is `df2$X2_`-th columns in the subset `X2_...` of `df2` and so on. Taking the first row in my example: `df$X1 = 3` so I need to take element from `df2$X1_3` (3d column). This element is 2. Then `df1$X2 = 1,2` and I need to take two elements, first from `df2$X2_1` and second from `df2$X2_2`. They are 1 and 2. All obtained elements for the first row I need to store as single vector in the first element of desired list and so on for every row.

In other words, for snippet above I need a list

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 1
```

`df1` consist of character variables.

How to create this list of elements in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option.  `gather` (in the `tidyr 1.0.0` - `pivot_longer` would be a replacement) the 'df1' to 'long' format, then split the 'val' column at `,` with `separate_rows`, and create a row/column index to extract the elements of from the 'df2' and `split` by the row number ('rn')

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
d1 <- df1 %>% 
       rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
       gather(key, val, -rn) %>%
       #pivot_longer(-rn, names_to= "key", values_to = "val") %>%
       separate_rows(val) %>%
       unite(key, key, val)
split(df2[cbind(as.numeric(d1$rn), match(d1$key, names(df2)))], d1$rn)
#$`1`
#[1] 2 1 2

#$`2`
#[1] 1 1 2

#$`3`
#[1] 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In *base* you can first split `df1$X2` and then subset by creating the column names using `paste` like:

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1[], as.character)

x <- colnames(df1)
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {
  df2[i, unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), function(j) {paste0(x[j], "_", strsplit(df1[i, x[j]], ",")[[1]])}))]
})
#[[1]]
#  X1_3 X2_1 X2_2
#1    2    1    2
#
#[[2]]
#  X1_2 X2_1 X2_3
#2    1    1    2
#
#[[3]]
#  X1_1 X2_1
#3    1    1
```

Comment: Thank you @GKi ! Could you help me with continuation of current question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164989/how-to-select-from-data-frame-using-column-orders-stored-in-two-another-data-fra ?

Comment: In real data I have X1, X2, ..., XN with N > 20