# How to select from data frame using column orders stored in two another data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have three data frames with equal number of rows. The snippet is

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1 = c('3', '2', '1'), X2 = c('1,2', '1,3', '1'))
df1
     Id X1  X2
1 12345  3 1,2
2 12346  2 1,3
3 12347  1   1

df2 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1_1 = c(3, 2, 1), X1_2 = c(1, 1, 2), X1_3 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_1 = c(1, 1, 1), X2_2 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_3 = c(3, 2, 2))
df2
     Id X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3
1 12345    3    1    2    1    2    3
2 12346    2    1    3    1    3    2
3 12347    1    2    3    1    3    2

df3 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1 = c(1, 2, 1), X2 = c(2, 1, 2))
df3
     Id X1 X2
1 12345  1  2
2 12346  2  1
3 12347  1  2
```

`df1` stores column numbers of `df2` from which I need to take elements. `df1$X1` is `df2$X1_`-th column in the subset `X1_...` of `df2`. `df1$X2` is `df2$X2_`-th columns in the subset `X2_...` of `df2` and so on. Taking the first row in my example: `df$X1 = 3` so I need to take element from `df2$X1_3` (3d column). This element is 2. Then `df1$X2 = 1,2` and I need to take two elements, first from `df2$X2_1` and second from `df2$X2_2`. They are 1 and 2. All obtained elements for the first row I need to store as single vector in the first element of desired list and so on for every row.

It's like [question with two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148340/how-to-select-from-data-frame-using-column-order-stored-in-another-data-frame-in) but now `df3` stores the final order of elements, so I need to get a list

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 1
```

What is the elegant way to create this list of elements in R?

**UPD:** All three data frames have NA. After replacing NA's by zeroes the first rows of real data frames could look like

**1)**

```
    df1[1, ]
         Id X1 X5 X6 X7 X8 X13 X14 X16 X19 X2        X3 X4 X9 X11 X12 X15 X18
1 123450744  1  5  1  3  2   0   0   0   3  6 1,2,4,6,7  1  0   0   0   0   5

    df2[1, ]
         Id X1_1 X1_2 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3 X2_4 X2_5 X2_6 X2_7 X2_8 X2_9 X3_1 X3_2 X3_3 X3_4 X3_5 X3_6 X3_7 X3_8 X3_9 X3_10 X3_11 X3_12 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3 X4_4 X4_5 X4_6 X4_7
1 123450744    1    2    4    2    5    7    3    6    1    8    9    1    7   10    6   11    5    8    9    4     3     2    12   11    1    6    4    2    5    8
  X4_8 X4_9 X4_10 X4_11 X4_12 X5_1 X5_2 X5_3 X5_4 X5_5 X5_6 X6_1 X6_2 X6_3 X6_4 X6_5 X6_6 X6_7 X7_1 X7_2 X7_3 X8_1 X8_2 X9_1 X9_2 X9_3 X10_1 X10_2 X10_3 X10_4 X10_5
1   10    7     3     9    12    4    2    5    1    3    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    1    2    3    1    2    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  X10_6 X10_7 X10_8 X11_1 X11_2 X11_3 X11_4 X11_5 X11_6 X11_7 X11_8 X11_9 X11_10 X11_11 X11_12 X11_13 X12_1 X12_2 X12_3 X12_4 X12_5 X12_6 X12_7 X12_8 X12_9 X12_10
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
  X12_11 X12_12 X13_1 X13_2 X13_3 X13_4 X13_5 X14_1 X14_2 X14_3 X14_4 X14_5 X15_1 X15_2 X15_3 X15_4 X15_5 X15_6 X15_7 X15_8 X15_9 X15_10 X15_11 X15_12 X16_1 X16_2
1      0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0     0
  X18_1 X18_2 X18_3 X18_4 X18_5 X18_6 X18_7 X19_1 X19_2 X19_3 X19_4 X19_5
1     3     5     4     2     6     1     7     1     2     3     4     5

    df3[1, ]
         Id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
1 123450744  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9  10
```

or

**2)**

```
df1  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1 X5 X6 X7 X8 X13 X14 X16 X19 X2        X3 X4 X9 X11 X12 X15 X18
 1 123450744  1  1  4  3  1   2   1   2   4 1,2,4,5,6,7,8  2 1,2,3,6,7 1,2,3   7 1,3,4 4,5,7,8,9   1")
 df2  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1_1 X1_2 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3 X2_4 X2_5 X2_6 X2_7 X2_8 X2_9 X3_1 X3_2 X3_3 X3_4 X3_5 X3_6 X3_7 X3_8 X3_9 X3_10 X3_11 X3_12 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3 X4_4 X4_5 X4_6 X4_7 X4_8 X4_9 X4_10 X4_11 X4_12 X5_1 X5_2 X5_3 X5_4 X5_5 X5_6 X6_1 X6_2 X6_3 X6_4 X6_5 X6_6 X6_7 X7_1 X7_2 X7_3 X8_1 X8_2 X9_1 X9_2 X9_3 X10_1 X10_2 X10_3 X10_4 X10_5 X10_6 X10_7 X10_8 X11_1 X11_2 X11_3 X11_4 X11_5 X11_6 X11_7 X11_8 X11_9 X11_10 X11_11 X11_12 X11_13 X12_1 X12_2 X12_3 X12_4 X12_5 X12_6 X12_7 X12_8 X12_9 X12_10 X12_11 X12_12 X13_1 X13_2 X13_3 X13_4 X13_5 X14_1 X14_2 X14_3 X14_4 X14_5 X15_1 X15_2 X15_3 X15_4 X15_5 X15_6 X15_7 X15_8 X15_9 X15_10 X15_11 X15_12 X16_1 X16_2 X18_1 X18_2 X18_3 X18_4 X18_5 X18_6 X18_7 X19_1 X19_2 X19_3 X19_4 X19_5
 1 123450744  1    2    2    7    8    3    1    5    6    4    9    5    6    8   10    7    3    1    9    2    11     4    12    5    8    1    3    6    9    4    7    2    10    11    12    3    5    4    1    2    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    1    2    3    1    2    1    2    3     3     4     2     8     5    1     7     6    10     3     6    12     7     9     8     4     5      1      2     11     13     6     7    10     9     4     3     5     2     1     11    8     12     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     7     4     2     6     3     5     1    10     8      9     11     12     1     2   5     4     1     2     6     3     7     1     2     3     4     5")
 df3  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="d X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
 1 123450744  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19")
 df1[,-1]  <- as.character(df1[,-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169427/10488504) this could be done like:

```
df1[,-1] <- lapply(df1[,-1], as.character)
df3[df3==0]  <- NA

lapply(setNames(df1$Id, df1$Id), function(Id) {
  x  <- unlist(df3[df3$Id==Id,-1])
  x <- names(sort(x[!is.na(x)])) #When NA is indicating that this column should not be used
  x  <- x[x %in% colnames(df1)] #This is only needed when df3 has colnames which are not in df1
  x  <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), function(j) {paste0(x[j], "_", strsplit(df1[df1$Id==Id, x[j]], ",")[[1]])}))
  df2[df2$Id==Id, x]
})
#For the original Question
#$`12345`
#  X1_3 X2_1 X2_2
#1    2    1    2
#
#$`12346`
#  X2_1 X2_3 X1_2
#2    1    2    1
#
#$`12347`
#  X1_1 X2_1
#3    1    1
#
#For UPD 1)
#$`123450744`
#  X1_1 X2_6 X3_1 X3_2 X3_4 X3_6 X3_7 X4_1 X5_5 X6_1 X7_3 X8_2 X18_5 X19_3
#1    1    6    1    7    6    5    8   11    3    1    3    2     6     3
#
#For UPD 2)
#$`123450744`
#  X1_1 X2_1 X2_2 X2_4 X2_5 X2_6 X2_7 X2_8 X3_2 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3 X4_6 X4_7 X5_1 X6_4 X7_3 X8_1 X9_1 X9_2 X9_3 X11_7 X12_1 X12_3 X12_4 X13_2 X14_1 X15_4 X15_5 X15_7 X15_8 X15_9 X16_2 X18_1 X19_4
#1    1    2    7    3    1    5    6    4    6    5    8    1    9    4    3    4    3    1    1    2    3     8     6    10     9     2     1     6     3     1    10     8     2     5     4
```

Data:

```
#Original
df1 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1 = c('3', '2', '1'), X2 = c('1,2', '1,3', '1'))
df2 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1_1 = c(3, 2, 1), X1_2 = c(1, 1, 2), X1_3 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_1 = c(1, 1, 1), X2_2 = c(2, 3, 3), X2_3 = c(3, 2, 2))
df3 <- data.frame(Id = c(12345, 12346, 12347), X1 = c(1, 2, 1), X2 = c(2, 1, 2))

#UPD 1)
df1  <- read.table(header=TRUE, , as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1 X5 X6 X7 X8 X13 X14 X16 X19 X2        X3 X4 X9 X11 X12 X15 X18
1 123450744  1  5  1  3  2   0   0   0   3  6 1,2,4,6,7  1  0   0   0   0   5")
df2  <- read.table(header=TRUE, , as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1_1 X1_2 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3 X2_4 X2_5 X2_6 X2_7 X2_8 X2_9 X3_1 X3_2 X3_3 X3_4 X3_5 X3_6 X3_7 X3_8 X3_9 X3_10 X3_11 X3_12 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3 X4_4 X4_5 X4_6 X4_7 X4_8 X4_9 X4_10 X4_11 X4_12 X5_1 X5_2 X5_3 X5_4 X5_5 X5_6 X6_1 X6_2 X6_3 X6_4 X6_5 X6_6 X6_7 X7_1 X7_2 X7_3 X8_1 X8_2 X9_1 X9_2 X9_3 X10_1 X10_2 X10_3 X10_4 X10_5 X10_6 X10_7 X10_8 X11_1 X11_2 X11_3 X11_4 X11_5 X11_6 X11_7 X11_8 X11_9 X11_10 X11_11 X11_12 X11_13 X12_1 X12_2 X12_3 X12_4 X12_5 X12_6 X12_7 X12_8 X12_9 X12_10 X12_11 X12_12 X13_1 X13_2 X13_3 X13_4 X13_5 X14_1 X14_2 X14_3 X14_4 X14_5 X15_1 X15_2 X15_3 X15_4 X15_5 X15_6 X15_7 X15_8 X15_9 X15_10 X15_11 X15_12 X16_1 X16_2 X18_1 X18_2 X18_3 X18_4 X18_5 X18_6 X18_7 X19_1 X19_2 X19_3 X19_4 X19_5
1 123450744    1    2    4    2    5    7    3    6    1    8    9    1    7   10    6   11    5    8    9    4     3     2    12   11    1    6    4    2    5    8   10    7     3     9    12    4    2    5    1    3    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    1    2    3    1    2    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0     0     3     5     4     2     6     1     7     1     2     3     4     5")
df3  <- read.table(header=TRUE, , as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
1 123450744  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9  10")

#UPD 2)
df1  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1 X5 X6 X7 X8 X13 X14 X16 X19 X2        X3 X4 X9 X11 X12 X15 X18
 1 123450744  1  1  4  3  1   2   1   2   4 1,2,4,5,6,7,8  2 1,2,3,6,7 1,2,3   7 1,3,4 4,5,7,8,9   1")
df2  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1_1 X1_2 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3 X2_4 X2_5 X2_6 X2_7 X2_8 X2_9 X3_1 X3_2 X3_3 X3_4 X3_5 X3_6 X3_7 X3_8 X3_9 X3_10 X3_11 X3_12 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3 X4_4 X4_5 X4_6 X4_7 X4_8 X4_9 X4_10 X4_11 X4_12 X5_1 X5_2 X5_3 X5_4 X5_5 X5_6 X6_1 X6_2 X6_3 X6_4 X6_5 X6_6 X6_7 X7_1 X7_2 X7_3 X8_1 X8_2 X9_1 X9_2 X9_3 X10_1 X10_2 X10_3 X10_4 X10_5 X10_6 X10_7 X10_8 X11_1 X11_2 X11_3 X11_4 X11_5 X11_6 X11_7 X11_8 X11_9 X11_10 X11_11 X11_12 X11_13 X12_1 X12_2 X12_3 X12_4 X12_5 X12_6 X12_7 X12_8 X12_9 X12_10 X12_11 X12_12 X13_1 X13_2 X13_3 X13_4 X13_5 X14_1 X14_2 X14_3 X14_4 X14_5 X15_1 X15_2 X15_3 X15_4 X15_5 X15_6 X15_7 X15_8 X15_9 X15_10 X15_11 X15_12 X16_1 X16_2 X18_1 X18_2 X18_3 X18_4 X18_5 X18_6 X18_7 X19_1 X19_2 X19_3 X19_4 X19_5
 1 123450744  1    2    2    7    8    3    1    5    6    4    9    5    6    8   10    7    3    1    9    2    11     4    12    5    8    1    3    6    9    4    7    2    10    11    12    3    5    4    1    2    6    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    1    2    3    1    2    1    2    3     3     4     2     8     5    1     7     6    10     3     6    12     7     9     8     4     5      1      2     11     13     6     7    10     9     4     3     5     2     1     11    8     12     1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5     7     4     2     6     3     5     1    10     8      9     11     12     1     2   5     4     1     2     6     3     7     1     2     3     4     5")
df3  <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE, text="Id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
 1 123450744  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19")
```

Comment: What if I have X1, X2, ..., X25, for example, in my data?

Comment: @drastega I have updated the answer to be able to be adapted to this condition.

Comment: in my case df1[,1], df1[,2], ..., df1[,25] are already characters, why do you need df1[,2]  <- as.character(df1[,2]) ? df3[,25] is also exist.

Comment: @drastega when they are already characters then you don't need `as.character`. But If I create the data using the code from your question they are factors.

Comment: I try to overcome NA's in my data by assigning them to zeroes (with appropriate data types) but in this case your code is not working. I also put x <- x[x!='X0'] after x  <- paste0("X",df3[i,2:20]) but it doesn't help.

Comment: @drastega I have added a variant which should work also for the case when you try to select columns which are not there.

Comment: in my data the first x is "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X0"  "X9"  "X10" and then I get an Error in strsplit(df1[i, x[j]], ",") : non-character argument

Comment: What do you get with `df1[1:2,]`  and `df3[1:2,]` ?

Comment: I added zeroes to all three data frames instead of NA. In my case df1[1, ] = 12345  1  5  1  3  2   0   0   0   3  6 1,2,4,6,7  1  0   0   0   0   5

Comment: @drastega It looks like that now your column-type is numeric but it needs to be character for all columns you are using from df1.

Comment: I've updated my question for clearance. My df1 is character.

Comment: @drastega Made another Update, working with the lager dataset. Hope it does now what you want.

Comment: I do not understand why your update doesn't work when meet df1 rows without zeroes.

Comment: I've updated my question by adding example of data (number 2) where your code crashes

Comment: @drastega That is because you have in `df3` the columns `X10` and `X17`, which are not in `df1`. So either you remove them from `df3` or add them in `df1` or use the updated answer.

Comment: I get an error when try to apply your code to UPD 2 but anyway thank you very much for your help @GKi !

Comment: @drastega On `UPD2` a closing bracket was missing when reading the data. Does it still create an error?

Comment: Yes, Error in strsplit(df1[df1$Id == Id, x[j]], ",") : non-character argument. The problem is not in bracket

Comment: @drastega You have to run the whole command starting with `df1[,-1] <- lapply(df1[,-1], as.character)` and not jump in at line 3 starting with `lapply(setNames(df1$Id, df1$Id), function(Id) {`